# Adding time to a time variable

Tags: bash, time

I'm trying to add 3 hours to my time variable like so:

```
today3AM=$(date -d "today 3AM" "+%Y%m%d%H" -u)

today6AM=$(date -d "${today3AM} + 3 hours" -u)

echo $today6AM
```

Something isn't quite right as it returns:

```
Wed Oct 3 03:00:00 UTC 202001
```

Comment: date format not applicable `"+%Y%m%d%H"` use `"+%Y-%m-%d %H"`

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass the 3AM variable back into date.

Just use this approach

```
$ today3AM=$(date -d "today 3AM" -u)
$ today6AM=$(date -d "today 3AM + 3 hours" -u)
$ echo $today3AM
Fri Jan 10 03:00:00 UTC 2020
$ echo $today6AM
Fri Jan 10 06:00:00 UTC 2020
$
```

Comment: Just in case if you want to add 3 hours to you previous time variable, you can do as:- today6AM=$(date -d "$today3AM + 3 hours" -u)

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd command doesn't know the format of `today3AM`. To get `today6AM` you can use something like

```
today=$(date -d "today 3AM" -u)
echo $today
Fri Jan 10 03:00:00 UTC 2020
today6am=$(date -u -d "${today} +3 hours")
echo $today6am
Fri Jan 10 06:00:00 UTC 2020
```

Now you can change `today3am` to suit.